# Are there fishes with a double circulatory system?

Tags: physiology, zoology, blood-circulation, ichthyology, circulatory-system

Our courseware materials say there are such fishes, but my Internet searches suggests fishes only have a single circulatory system.

Comment: Can you please put a little more effort into your question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that lungfish display the beginnings of a double circulatory system:

[image]